# How many types of Singularities has string theory successfully resolved?

Tags: black-holes, string-theory, singularities

Except for proposing the fuzzball as a solution for black hole singularity, has string theory successfully explained/dealt with any other form of spacelike or timelike singularities? Kindly explain

Comment: Not at all an expert, but I think that it resolves all the singularities in principle in certain asymptomatic AdS spacetimes due to the AdS/CFT correspondence. I might very well be erred.

Comment: Also, you might be interested in a recent critique of the fuzzball program: https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.10616.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am not so sure about the big bang singularity though. Has string theory given any stable solution? I don't know. There are models though that seeks to replace the classical singularity by replacing the classical geodesics with quantum or Bohmian trajectories. But they don't apply string theory. I will go through the paper given in the link. Suvrat Raju's ideas always make us think about these problems in a different way

Comment: @DvijMankad For black holes embedded in asymptotically AdS spaces, even if there is a dual CFT, AdS/CFT doesn't describe the black hole's interior. Comment to OP: By "resolution of singularities" you might want to look at the identification of Dbranes with black p-branes, which are higher dimensional generalization of charged black holes.

Comment: @BruceLee Yes, I know there are issues with describing the black-hole interior. In particular, there has been no explicit success in describing the interior using the AdS/CFT correspondence. But, if the AdS/CFT correspondence is true in its entirety then, in principle, there must be a consistent description of the interior using the AdS/CFT correspondence. This is what I meant. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @DvijMankad No, the relevant idea here is that even if you specify field values in the boundary of any black hole embedded in AdS, be it Schwarzschild or Reissner-Nordstrom or anything else; then the black hole interior always lies outside the domain of dependence of the specified boundary condition. This statement is independent of AdS-CFT's correctness. Check out Page 7 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.02812.pdf; this gives the reason why this is so.

Comment: @DvijMankad Specifically, check out the last para of Page 7. It is an interesting paper.

Comment: @BruceLee Thank you for pointing out the paper. I am really not up to the mark for understanding the paper fully but I will try to get the gist at least.

Comment: @DvijMankad Actually you are partially correct regarding your previous statement. There is a paper by two of the above authors (PR), https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.6335; which explicitly construct bulk operators in the interior of a black hole; assuming that the mapping of CFT operators to bulk operators depends on the state of CFT. Usually when somebody refers to a paper, try to get these 3 things done: read the abstract, the introduction and the conclusion. In case you find something really interesting and worth your time, then work it out. All the best!